# Is this sum with fractional part function and harmonic numbers convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

About an hour ago I went to bed and the following question came, so I got up from the bed in order to share it with you, and because I would like to see the solution.

I apologize if this is something too elementary but at the moment I do not see how to solve it.

And the question is:

> Is the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\{H_i\}}{H_i}$ convergent?

Here $\{\}$ is the *fractional part* function defined as $\{x\}=x- \lfloor {x} \rfloor$ (for positive $x$) and $H_n$ is the $n-$th harmonic number ($H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \dfrac {1}{k}$).

Comment: I don't see how. The denominator is about $\log n,$ and the fractional part averages out at $1/2,$ meaning there are long strings where it is bigger than $1/2$

Comment: @WillJagy I think I understand what you said, but could it be that the fractional part of harmonic numbers will more often take values considerably less than 1/2, where with  "more often" I want to say "in such a way that it could make the sum in the question convergent"?

Comment: I think you are right, something is clearer now, if you wish you can add some details and turn that comment into an answer.

Comment: No, eventually it levels out to a great degree, the fractional part (the numerator) spends almost exactly half the time between $0$ and $1/2,$ half the time between $1/2$ and just below $1.$ Suggest you run a computer program on that aspect tomorrow.

Comment: Actually, i would rather you investigate a little yourself, maybe just computer experiments. You will learn a little more that way, and it will stay with you longer.

Comment: @WillJagy I think I get it, the reason for that behavior is, as I see it now, in the very very slow divergence of harmonic numbers. Because of that the fractional part of harmonic numbers stays for a long periods of time between 0 and 1/2 and then between 1/2 and 1 and for approximately the same time, is this right?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: @WillJagy Ok, thank you for your help.